# Access interface property value in same interface

Tags: typescript, interface, generic-interface

I'm wondering if it's possible to access an interface prop value in the same interface declaration in order to set the types dynamically.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
export type MethodNames = "IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed" | "UpdateStammFallmanager";

export interface IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed {
  plcParameter : StammFallmanagerParameter
}

export interface UpdateStammFallmanager {
  plcParameter : StammFallmanagerParameter
}

export interface ServerTaskParam<T> extends system.ServerTaskParam<T> {
  name       : `${Class.NAME}`,
  methodName : MethodNames,
  paramObj   : // here depending on the passed methodname type should be IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed or UpdateStammFallmanager
  // paramObj   : T -> this is what I use atm but I want to make it more dynamic
}
```

Note that there could be more `MethodNames`.

What I want to achieve is that when passing name and methodName the intellisense should be able to tell me directly which type of object should be passed as `paramObj`.

It should be something like this if possible:

```
export interface ServerTaskParam extends system.ServerTaskParam {
  name       : `${Class.NAME}`,
  methodName : MethodNames,
  paramObj   : [ methodName ] -> use methodName value to refer to one or the other interface in the same namespace (pseudo syntax)
}
```

I'm searching the net for a while now but couldn't find anything. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a composite type holding every possible interface so you can use this "higher type" with its keys like so:

```
export interface IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed {
  plcParameter : StammFallmanagerParameter
}

export interface UpdateStammFallmanager {
  plcParameter : StammFallmanagerParameter
}

interface Methods {
  IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed: IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed;
  UpdateStammFallmanager: UpdateStammFallmanager;
}

export interface ServerTaskParam<K extends keyof Methods> extends system.ServerTaskParam<T> {
  name       : `${Class.NAME}`,
  methodName : K,
  paramObj   : Methods[K]
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, not exactly, I don't want to just restrict it, I'd like the interface to understand what exactly is to expect for `paramObj`if one or the other value is passed to `methodName`. If I can manage to do this I wouldn't need `T` anymore.

Comment: I updated my answer to try to address the problem that you face.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is just a union:

```
export type ServerTaskParam = ({
  name       : `${Class.NAME}`,
  methodName : "IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed",
  paramObj   : IsFallmanagerUpdateAllowed
} | {
  name       : `${Class.NAME}`,
  methodName : "UpdateStammFallmanager",
  paramObj   : UpdateStammFallmanager
}) & system.ServerTaskParam
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCywYAsIBMByAhgLbADOcAvHAEQCSZAYoQDYvGEB2hA5sFAFUwuQjGABBNhADuwXDTgAfWkJFiAyjBLFmbDtz5QaAbgBQp0JFhwAlpzFQAZoQDGqBrvZde-VaIlSsrhwAN6mcHBgLC4ACoRQJJj8cABccGQwUHY8pgC%205pbQ8HYOzm5wfhpaxDqsXgbJYRFRsfGJDqnpmdl5BeBFCMio6vwAbvwAKoRkANZxCcRUoeFwpNh4RKSd9Ex1%20j6Cwv6SLDJyNAA0K2BtxADyAEYAVhGdHnvehpUBp0F5SssImscAREttvpptJ59oZLtdbo8XhE0hDqrU9J9%20HkgA)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, any chance to extend the `system.ServerTaskParam` interface with unions? Would maybe have to rethink what extends what, I could maybe pass the union type to `system.ServerTaskParam` to achieve what I need. Will try it.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to show how `system.ServerTaskParam` would be extended in this case.

Comment: I tried it but the intellisense doesn't seem to work as well as with interfaces like this.